# Keeping ADB permissions while USB tethering

Tags: adb, linux, permissions, usb-debugging, usb-tethering

It seems that I can only get ADB permissions for my device only while in MTP or PTP mode and NOT in USB tethering mode, which is what I need.

I have done plenty of research but I stumbled upon so much contradicting and very old information that I can no longer see how to proceed.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831807/usb-tether-and-debug-at-the-same-time) they say that it is not possible, but it dates back to 2012. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226924/is-it-possible-to-usb-tether-an-android-device-using-adb-through-the-terminal) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29954/is-it-possible-to-activate-the-usb-tethering-android-setting-from-the-command) they propose to invoke the shell via ADB to put the device in USB tethering mode (which works for me as well) but also to disable it, which in my case fails since as once stepped away from MTP or PTP mode I no longer have permissions for my device.

Then I found [this interesting post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/160575/why-does-one-type-of-tethering-obstruct-mtp-while-another-doesnt) which seems relevant but does not provide a complete solution. [This](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128609/adb-devices-gives-no-permission-when-on-charge-only) also looks relevant but it does not touch the tethering case.

So, once and for all, how do I **keep ADB permissions** for my device when it is ***NOT*** in **MTP or PTP** mode? I only care about recent Android versions. I obviously have **root** access for my device as well the possibility to deploy custom ROMs, although, for personal taste, I tend to stick to LineageOS.

---

Additional note: this is the error that I get when not in MTP/PTP:

```
$ adb devices 
List of devices attached
2d8568f6    no permissions; see [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html]

$ adb shell
error: insufficient permissions for device
See [http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html] for more information
```

Unfortunately the link is quite useless, but it seems that ADB identifies and communicates with the device, but this does not accept any request.

I don't think that this has something to do with my PC, the udev rules are in place, plus ADB works fine when the device is in MTP or PTP mode.

Here is a screenshot ([click for video browsing to that menu](https://youtu.be/1xknCcK_w00)):

[image: dsc]

---

When in MTP mode I can open a shell via ADB, this is what I see:

```
$ su

# pwd
/

# ls -lah                                                                                                   
total 1.0M
drwxr-xr-x  18 root   root   4.0K 2008-12-31 19:30 .
drwxr-xr-x  18 root   root   4.0K 2008-12-31 19:30 ..
dr-xr-xr-x  56 root   root      0 1971-04-23 21:51 acct
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     11 2008-12-31 19:30 bin -> /system/bin
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     50 2008-12-31 19:30 bugreports -> /data/user_de/0/com.android.shell/files/bugreports
drwxrwx---   6 system cache  4.0K 1971-04-23 21:51 cache
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     13 2008-12-31 19:30 charger -> /sbin/charger
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root      0 1970-01-01 01:00 config
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     17 2008-12-31 19:30 d -> /sys/kernel/debug
drwxrwx--x  42 system system 4.0K 2020-05-02 11:50 data
lrw-------   1 root   root     23 2008-12-31 19:30 default.prop -> system/etc/prop.default
drwxr-xr-x  17 root   root   3.4K 2018-03-20 08:10 dev
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     11 2008-12-31 19:30 dsp -> /vendor/dsp
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     11 2008-12-31 19:30 etc -> /system/etc
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     20 2008-12-31 19:30 firmware -> /vendor/firmware_mnt
-rwxr-x---   1 root   shell  2.1M 2008-12-31 19:30 init
-rwxr-x---   1 root   shell  1.2K 2008-12-31 19:30 init.environ.rc
-rwxr-x---   1 root   shell   29K 2008-12-31 19:30 init.rc
-rwxr-x---   1 root   shell  7.5K 2008-12-31 19:30 init.usb.configfs.rc
-rwxr-x---   1 root   shell  5.5K 2008-12-31 19:30 init.usb.rc
-rwxr-x---   1 root   shell   511 2008-12-31 19:30 init.zygote32.rc
-rwxr-x---   1 root   shell   875 2008-12-31 19:30 init.zygote64_32.rc
drwx------   2 root   root    16K 2008-12-31 19:30 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  12 root   system  260 1971-04-23 21:51 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4.0K 2008-12-31 19:30 odm
drwxr-xr-x   2 root   root   4.0K 2008-12-31 19:30 oem
dr-xr-xr-x 512 root   root      0 1970-01-01 01:00 proc
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     15 2008-12-31 19:30 product -> /system/product
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root   4.0K 2008-12-31 19:30 res
drwxr-xr-x   3 root   root    300 1971-04-23 21:51 sbin
lrw-r--r--   1 root   root     21 2008-12-31 19:30 sdcard -> /storage/self/primary
drwxr-xr-x   4 root   root     80 2020-02-27 08:07 storage
dr-xr-xr-x  12 root   root      0 1971-04-23 21:51 sys
drwxr-xr-x  17 root   root   4.0K 2018-03-20 02:40 system
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root   5.2K 2008-12-31 19:30 ueventd.rc
drwxr-xr-x  15 root   root   4.0K 2008-12-31 19:30 vendor
-rw-r--r--   1 root   root    524 2008-12-31 19:30 verity_key
```

I can open the various `.rc` files in there (with `nano` or `/sbin/.magisk/busybox/vi`) but in readonly mode. I might be able to get rw permissions from recovery, but still I would not know what to change.

Comment: That seem to be a device specific problem (-> edit your question and add device details). My Sony XA2 works out of the box with USB tethering and ADB at the same time (however MTP seem to be disabled while USB tethering is active).

Comment: @Robert I am trying with a lenovo k6 (karate k33a48). I have the feeling that in the past it used to work, but I cannot remember what ROM I was using. I expect this to be a software issue, possibly device unrelated.

Comment: Note: Your question is a bit misleading as you always talk about "adb permission". However this is not a permission problem but a configuration of the USB interface. Each physical USB device can have multiple logical devices active at the same time (on my device one for "Remote NDIS" and one for adb or one for adb and one for MTP). On Windows you can view them nicely in the device manager grouped by a USB compound device (virtual device that combines the logical USB devices). Hence your question is how to activate RNDIS and adb at the same time.

Comment: You should add this very important info into your question and not hide in comments. However I still don't think that this is a permission problem. The adb permission uses public key auth, hence the permission can't just change. I suspect a bug in the firmware of your device or a general bug if others can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Robert I will just try another rom, but It's a pity because that doesn't lead to any understanding of the issue.

Comment: If your device is rooted and it uses `sysfs` interfaces to configure USB functions, you can edit `init`'s `.rc` files to write `adb` and `rndis` at the same time (as it writes `adb` and `mtp` together). The same should be achievable if your device uses `configfs` interfaces. // If the problem is only about ADB permissions (and not that tethering and ADB cannot be turned ON simultaneously), all that you need to do is add the USB VID/PID to your device manager (e.g. `udevd`) on PC so that proper permissions are set on USB interfaces in `/dev`. There's nothing to be done on phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "???" and no permissions when using 'adb devices' on Linux](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/122644/getting-and-no-permissions-when-using-adb-devices-on-linux)

Comment: @IrfanLatif not really. My udev rule is in place and works fine when in MTP/PTP mode. The answer which suggest to change usb mode is quite silly in my case. See the edits for the `.rc` files.

Comment: MTP/PTP uses a different USB VID/PID, usually that provided by Google in AOSP. Tethering (RNDIS) is a hardware-specific USB mode, so OEM's VID/PID is exposed to PC. Mostly Linux distros recognize MTP/PTP out of box because that's a generic case. But there is a long list of Android phone vendors, so not every Linux distro recognizes every vendor (VID) and every of its product (PID). I suggest you read about how USB VID/PID works, instead of blindly resisting.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Thank you for your persistence. That was indeed the case: the product ID changed slightly when in tethering mode and I did not have the proper udev rule. I transferred this knowledge in the archlinux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android_Debug_Bridge#No_permissions_error If you make your comment an answer I would be happy to accept and upvote it :D

Comment: @DarioP I'm glad it helped. I think the question I linked already includes the relevant answers. Reposting isn't encouraged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107522/discussion-between-dariop-and-irfan-latif).

Comment: This is the answer to my question: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/195443/322110

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I think it is caused by some bug or misconfiguration in the ROM.

As a workaround, I figured out enabling the option *ADB over network* from the *Developer options* allowed me to connect using adb while having USB tethering mode turned on. However you have to be careful not to enable that option on untrusted networks (untrusted wifi or 3G) because it allows remote access to your device over TCP to anybody on that network.